# Single node kubernetes cluster scale up

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have single node kubenertes cluster running on GKE. All the load is running on single node separated by namesapces.

now i would like to implement the auto-scaling. Is it possible i can scale mircoservices to new node but one pod is running My main node only.

what i am thinking

Main node : Running everything with 1 pod avaibility (Redis, Elasticsearch)

Scaled up node : Scaled up replicas only of stateless microservice

so is there any way i can implemet this using `node auto scaeler` or using `affinity`.

Issue is that right now i am running graylog, elasticsearch and redis and rabbitmq on single node having `statefulsets` and backed by volume i have to redeploy everything edit yaml file for adding `affinity` to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly but if I do then you may try to use taints and tolerations (node affinity). Taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. All the details are available in the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/).

Comment: thanks for writing an answer but what if i have not initially applied affinity to YAML file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the issue you have is that the persistent volumes bound to your StatefulSets are only accessible from one node, then you can use the [nodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#node-affinity) field to constraint where the StatefulSet Pods can be scheduled. As mentioned in the documentation:

> A PV can specify node affinity to define constraints that limit what
>   nodes this volume can be accessed from. Pods that use a PV will only
>   be scheduled to nodes that are selected by the node affinity.